# How to add text/image on time series jfree chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Requirement: i need to display **toolTip(No data available) and image** on time series chart which have null data ie;  **Image 2 on gray color area**.
Problem:I am not able to get it.
Image With some data ie; **series1.addOrUpdate(absoluteMSecond, data[i]);**
[image]

Image with null data ie; **series1.addOrUpdate(absoluteMSecond, null);**
[image]

COde:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardXYToolTipGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.Millisecond;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class TextOnJFreeChart extends ApplicationFrame {

  public TextOnJFreeChart(final String title) {
    super(title);
    final XYDataset data = createDataset();
    final JFreeChart chart = createChart(data);
    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
  }

  private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset data) {

    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Text/ToolTip Trying Demo", "X", "Y", data, true, true, true);
    final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    plot.getRenderer().setToolTipGenerator(StandardXYToolTipGenerator.getTimeSeriesInstance());
    plot.setNoDataMessage("Hai it is ok if i get this message.......");

    final DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis("Time");
    domainAxis.setUpperMargin(0.50);
    plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);

    final ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(0.30);
    rangeAxis.setLowerMargin(0.50);

    return chart;
  }

  private XYDataset createDataset() {

    final TimeSeriesCollection result = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    result.addSeries(createSupplier1Bids());
    return result;
  }

  private TimeSeries createSupplier1Bids() 
  {

    double[] data = {200.0, 195.0, 190.0, 188.0, 185.0, 180.0};
    long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Millisecond absoluteMSecond = getTimeInMillisecondFormat(timeStamp, 0L);
    final TimeSeries series1 = new TimeSeries("Supplier 1", Millisecond.class);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      absoluteMSecond = getTimeInMillisecondFormat(timeStamp + i * 1000, 0L);
      //series1.addOrUpdate(absoluteMSecond, data[i]);
      series1.addOrUpdate(absoluteMSecond, null);
    }
    return series1;
  }

  public Millisecond getTimeInMillisecondFormat(long timeStamp, long startTime)
  {
    try
    {
      long diff = timeStamp - startTime;
      Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
      calender.setTimeInMillis(diff);
      Millisecond elapsedMSecond = new Millisecond(calender.getTime());
      return (elapsedMSecond);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final TextOnJFreeChart demo = new TextOnJFreeChart("Text/ToolTip Trying Demo");
    demo.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
    demo.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the desired image to the plot's [`setBackgroundImage()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Plot.html#setBackgroundImage-java.awt.Image-) method, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9592941/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906497/230513).

The implementation of [`getToolTipText()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#getToolTipText-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-) in `ChartPanel` will return `null` if the dataset  is empty, but you can override the method to return a suitable alternative string.